# Create outlook message with attachment using vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, outlook

I would like to create an outlook message with a subject and some attachments for the user to send when they are ready. I have the file paths for the attachments. How would I go about doing this?

Basically the user needs to click a button on the application and that open an outlook message window with a predefined message and a few attachments. They should then be able to modify and add the required "To" etc before sending via outlook.

Thanks!

Comment: Three words: "Outlook Object Model". There is also "direct" MAPI access, if you like pain, Redemption, which is an awesome library, and CDO.

Comment: C# or VB.Net - those tag are conflicting?

Comment: Your question shows a lack of research, I put the title of your question in google and found a KB article. If you want users to see the email before they send it, simply swap the line of code `oMsg.Send();` and change it to Display as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861853.aspx

Comment: OOM sounds about right - didn't matter between c# and vb.net - I imagine for this it would've been interchangeable.

Comment: It was the send vs display I had issues with -didn't know the term to display but I had seen that article. Thanks.

Comment: OOM stands for Out Of Memory exception - probably better to keep calling  "Outlook Object Model" or VSTO for short

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson - working perfectly. And will use VSTO henceforth. Used OOM (yes I know Out Of Memory exception) from your answer: "Send Attachment Using OOM in Visual Basic .NET"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to send attachments in an e-mail message by using Visual Basic .NET**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313803

Here is the C# version of the code:

```
void Main()
{
    // Create an Outlook application.
    Outlook._Application oApp;
    oApp = new Outlook.Application();

    // Create a new MailItem.
    Outlook._MailItem oMsg;
    oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    oMsg.Subject = "Send Attachment Using OOM in Visual Basic .NET";
    oMsg.Body = "Hello World" + vbCr + vbCr;

    // TODO: Replace with a valid e-mail address.
    oMsg.To = "user@example.com";

    // Add an attachment
    // TODO: Replace with a valid attachment path.
    string sSource = "C:\\Temp\\Hello.txt";
    // TODO: Replace with attachment name
    string sDisplayName = "Hello.txt";

    string sBodyLen = oMsg.Body.Length;
    Outlook.Attachments oAttachs = oMsg.Attachments;
    Outlook.Attachment oAttach;
    oAttach = oAttachs.Add(sSource, , sBodyLen + 1, sDisplayName);

    // Send
    oMsg.Send();

    // Clean up
    oApp = null;
    oMsg = null;
    oAttach = null;
    oAttachs = null;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend an explicit `ReleaseComObject` on *at least* the message -- Outlook message caching *will* bite if not done. This is my warning backed by countless hours of tracking down subtle bugs caused by the failure to do so. (Also the attachments, but that's not nearly as critical, and if you've gone that far, might as well also treat the application as an unmanaged resource as well... but *at least* do it for the messages.)

Comment: @pst thanks for pointing this out, Omar here is a handy link to understand how to deal with mixing Managed Memory Management with Unmanaged Code Memory Management: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop

Comment: @pst thanks I did :)  - thanks, got it working today as I needed it :)

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson Thanks for the help and the article! Much appreciated.